# Right curly brace at the end of an equation

Tags: equations

I'm trying to write this equation:
[image]

I'm facing problem with the **curly brace**.

I tried using **\right**

```
\begin{equation}
2 \uparrow \uparrow k \stackrel{\text{def}} = \left.2^{2^{2^{.^{.^{.^{{2}}}}}}}\right\}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

which isn't what we want.

and the same result using **\bigg** :

```
\begin{equation}
2 \uparrow \uparrow k \stackrel{\text{def}}= 2^{2^{2^{.^{.^{.^{{2}}}}}}}\bigg\}.
\end{equation}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code you tried (complete, short, **compilable**) and describe exact the problem that occurs.

Answer (score 6):

One way to achieve right curly braces is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\[
\left.\begin{array}{c}
2\uparrow\uparrow k = 2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}
  \end{array}\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Raise a `\Big` brace:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
2 \mathbin{\uparrow\uparrow} k
\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}
  2^{2^{2^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{2}}}}}}
  \raisebox{\depth}{$\Bigr\}\scriptstyle k$}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `blkarray`, `yhmath` (for its `\adots` command) and the `\upuparrows` symbol from `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, yhmath, blkarray}
\newcommand\eqdef{\ensuremath{\stackrel{\text{def}}{ = }}}

\begin{document}

     \[ 2\upuparrows k\eqdef
     \raisebox{.15\height}{$ \begin{blockarray}{@{}c<{\mskip-4mu}\Right{\}}{$\scriptstyle k $}} 2^{2^{2^{\adots^{\raisebox{-1.25\height}{$\scriptscriptstyle 2 $}}}}}
     \end{blockarray} $}
     \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]