# Help me typeset math formulas!

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, arrays

I want to type these but i just don't know how to do it. 
Here are the pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please give me the code to each one of them. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What don't you know how to do in these formulæ?

Comment: Are you familiar with TeX's math modes -- inline math mode and display math mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple code for the other two formulæ. The `amsmath`  package defines 5 matrix environments,with different delimiters. The `mathtools` package is  an extension of the former, which defines starred variants of these matrix environment, which add the possibility of choosing the alignment of all columns via  an optional argument – the default is `c`  (centred, as in `amsmath`), but you also can have `r`ight or `l`eft-aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{Bmatrix*}[l]
  G\in V_{\tau}(x) \Rightarrow V_{\tau}(x) \neq\varnothing \\
\forall v \in V_{\tau}(x) \Rightarrow x \in v
\end{Bmatrix*} \]%

\[ \begin{Bmatrix*}[l]
  x\in G_1\cap G_2 \\
G_1,G_2 \in \tau_v
\end{Bmatrix*} \Rightarrow \begin{Bmatrix*}[l]
  x \in G_1\, / \,G_1 \in \tau_v\\
  x \in G_2\, / \,G_2 \in \tau_v
\end{Bmatrix*}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: The first formula is easily typed with the `rcases` environment, from `mathtools`:

```
\[ \begin{rcases}
  \exists G_1 \in\tau \,/\, x \in G_1\subset v_1 \\
    v_1\subset v_2
\end{rcases} \Rightarrow x \in G_1 \subset v_2 \]%
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you take a look at the documentations of `amsmath` and `mathtools` to begin with, and also to read a tutorial on typing mathematics, such as Herbert Voß’ `Math mode`.

Comment: @Bernard Oh, nice! I didn't know about `rcases`. I take it its other functionality (e.g. use of `&`) is identical to that of `cases`?

Comment: Yes. You also have   `rcases*` (after `&`, you're in text mode) and `drcases(*)`  all maths inside are in \displaystyle., and if course `dcases(*)` with the brace on the left.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
    \left. % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298837/right-curly-brace-at-the-end-of-an-equation
        \begin{array}{l}
            \exists G_1 \in \tau \ / \ x\in G_1\subset \nu_1 \\
            \nu_1 \subset \nu_2
        \end{array}
    \right\}
    \implies
    x\in G_1\subset\nu_2
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

The other ones should be pretty similar. See also [How to write an m⨉n matrix in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69997/how-to-write-an-m%E2%A8%89n-matrix-in-latex)

(`\[` and `\]` start and end a centered math environment; `\left` and `\right` automatically size the delimiters (e.g. parentheses, brackets, etc.) that come after them (`.` just means no delimiter, but is needed because every `\left` or `\right` needs its closing `\right` / opening `\left`). The `\` add a space before and after the `/`, which is just the usual slash. `\\` adds a line break. The backslashes before the other words assign them special meanings, e.g. particular symbols or environments.)

Comment: Thank you so much.